# Can we login using other Directory users of same Azure account

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

My Azure Active Directory have 2 directories:

1. User1Directory
2. User2Directory

My app configured with User1Directory and I successfully logged in using User1Directory users, but I want login using User2Directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so you have 2 Azure AD tenants (directories).
If you want to allow sign in from multiple tenants, you need to [make your app multi-tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant).

Then you have a couple options for how you can handle authentication.
Your app will regardless have to check the issuer of tokens as changing an app to multi-tenant allows login *with any tenant*.
You probably want to check the issuer is one of those 2 tenants.

Your app could offer two login buttons, one which redirects to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant1-id/...` and the other to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant2-id/...`.
This approach supports external guest users in those tenants as well.

The other approach is that you can instead always redirect users to authenticate with `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/...`.
This will allow the user to sign in with any Azure AD tenant.
It's simpler from your app's side but it does prevent external guest users in those tenants from signing in as the organizations endpoint (like the common endpoint) always logs the user in to their "home" tenant, making the issuer that home tenant.

Comment: Thanks, that issue solved but now I want to sign in using Google account. Can you please help me